# How to Replace Fragment at runtime with the ChildFragmentManager and this fragment without Title of PagerSlidingTabStrip Xamarin.Android

Tags: android, android-fragments, xamarin.android, android-viewpager

I want to Change the Pager Layout at runtime with other fragment but without the PagerSlidingTabStrip Title. How .I can make it .
Second how .I can call method home Fragment in another fragments.

Here is The Home Layout

```
     <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_marginBottom="50dp"
            android:id="@+id/SlidingStrips"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:layout_below="@id/AcountBalance">
     <com.refractored.PagerSlidingTabStrip
        android:id="@+id/tabs"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:pstsPaddingMiddle="true"
        app:pstsDividerWidth="1dp"
        app:pstsDividerPadding="5dp"
        app:pstsDividerColor="#50FFFFFF"
        android:textColor="#50FFFFFF"
        app:pstsTextColorSelected="@android:color/white"
        app:pstsIndicatorColor="@android:color/white"
        app:pstsUnderlineColor="@android:color/white" />
<!--Change this to true if you want to center items-->
              
    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/pager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        tools:context=".HomeFragmentLayout" />
           
        </LinearLayout>
```

And how i'm Adding fragments here is the ChildFragments that added with the parent fragment these two fragments add two tabs with Hour and day Tabs.

```
 public class HomeFragment : Fragment, IOnTabReselectedListener, ViewPager.IOnPageChangeListener
    {
        View view;
        private MyPagerAdapter adapter;
        private int count = 1;
        private int currentColor;
        List<Android.Support.V4.App.Fragment> fragments = new List<Android.Support.V4.App.Fragment>();
        public static ViewPager pager;
        private PagerSlidingTabStrip tabs;

        public override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);

            // Create your fragment here
        }

        public static HomeFragment NewInstance()
        {
            var frag1 = new HomeFragment { Arguments = new Bundle() };
            return frag1;
        }


        public override View OnCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {

            base.OnCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);
            if (view == null)
            {
                view = inflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.HomeFragmentLayout, container, false);
             
                return view;
            }
            else
            {

                return view;
            }

        
        }
        public override void OnViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            base.OnViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
            try
            {
                fragments.Add(new HourlyFragment());
                fragments.Add(new DayFragment());
             
                adapter = new MyPagerAdapter(ChildFragmentManager, fragments);
                pager = view.FindViewById<ViewPager>(Resource.Id.pager);
                tabs = View.FindViewById<PagerSlidingTabStrip>(Resource.Id.tabs);
                pager.Adapter = adapter;
                tabs.SetViewPager(pager);

                var pageMargin = (int)TypedValue.ApplyDimension(ComplexUnitType.Dip, 4, Resources.DisplayMetrics);
                pager.PageMargin = pageMargin;
                pager.CurrentItem = 0;
                tabs.OnTabReselectedListener = this;
                tabs.OnPageChangeListener = this;
              
            }
            catch (System.Exception ex)
            {

               
            }
        
        }
       .// public  void ReplaceFragment(Fragment fragment)
        //{
        //    try
        //    {
        //        FragmentManager manager = ChildFragmentManager;
        //        FragmentTransaction transaction = manager.BeginTransaction();
        //        transaction.Add(Resource.Id.content_frame, fragment);
        //        transaction.Commit();
        //    }
        //    catch (System.Exception ex)
        //    {

               
        //    }


        //}

        public void OnTabReselected(int position)
        {
            Toast.MakeText(Context.ApplicationContext, "Tab reselected: " + position, ToastLength.Short).Show();
        }

        public void OnPageScrollStateChanged(int state)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Page scroll state changed: " + state);
        }

        public void OnPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Page Scrolled");
        }

        public void OnPageSelected(int position)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Page selected: " + position);
        }
        
    }
```

Here is the pager Adapter

```
public class MyPagerAdapter : FragmentPagerAdapter
    {
        List<Android.Support.V4.App.Fragment> fragments;
        private readonly string[] Titles =
        {
            "Hour", "Day"
        };

        public MyPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm, List<Android.Support.V4.App.Fragment> fragments) : base(fm)
        {
            this.fragments = fragments;

        }
        public override ICharSequence GetPageTitleFormatted(int position)
        {
      
            return new String(Titles[position]);
        }

   
        //}
        public override int Count { get { return fragments.Count; } }

        public override Fragment GetItem(int position)
        {
            return fragments[position];
        }

        public override long GetItemId(int position)
        {
            return base.GetItemId(position);
        }
       
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do like below,suppose you need to call the replacement method in HomeFragment.

Add below codes in your **MyPagerAdapter** class (how to replace the fragment at runtime):

```
private bool[] flags;
public override int GetItemPosition(Java.Lang.Object @object)
    {
        return PositionNone;
    }

public override Java.Lang.Object InstantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position)
    {

        if (flags != null && flags[position])
        {
            /** Get the cached fragment and replace it with a new fragment*/
            Android.Support.V4.App.Fragment fragment = (Android.Support.V4.App.Fragment)base.InstantiateItem(container, position);
            string fragmentTag = fragment.Tag;
            Android.Support.V4.App.FragmentTransaction ft = fm.BeginTransaction();
            ft.Remove(fragment);
            fragment = fragments[position];
            ft.Add(container.Id, fragment, fragmentTag);
            ft.Attach(fragment);
            ft.Commit();
            /** Set to false when the replacement is complete*/
            flags[position] = false;
            if (fragment != null)
            {
                return fragment;
            }
            else
            {
                return base.InstantiateItem(container, position);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            return base.InstantiateItem(container, position);
        }

        
    }
  public void setFragments(List<Android.Support.V4.App.Fragment> fragments)
    {
        if (this.fragments != null)
        {
            flags = new bool[fragments.Count];
            for (int i = 0; i < fragments.Count; i++)
            {
                flags[i] = true;
            }
        }
        this.fragments = fragments;
        NotifyDataSetChanged();
    }
```

then the replace method in your HomeFragment :

```
  public void ReplaceFragment()
    {
        fragments[0] = new NewFragment(); //suppose you want to replace the first HourlyFragment
        fragments[1] = new DayFragment();
        adapter.setFragments(fragments);


    }
```

in the other fragment(for example a click event),you could call the replace method which in the **HomeFragment** like :

```
 private void Button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        foreach (Android.Support.V4.App.Fragment fragment in Activity.SupportFragmentManager.Fragments)
        {
            if (fragment is HomeFragment)
            {
                ((HomeFragment)fragment).ReplaceFragment();
            }
        }
       
    }
```